# Convert raw bytes into primitive types in c/objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, byte, nsdata, primitive

I have some bytes in an NSData object.

I'd like to convert the first four bytes into an unsigned big endian int.

The next 2 into an unsigned big endian short and the next four into an unsigned big endian long.

In general I need to figure out how to break up the string into whatever primitive types I expect.

This is my best attempt at getting an int from the first 4 bytes:

```
int position = 0;
const unsigned char *firstFourBytes;
[stream getBytes:&firstFourBytes range:NSMakeRange(position , 4)];
uint32_t test = *(uint32_t*)firstFourBytes;
position+=4;
```

Can anyone tell me the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is incorrect:

```
int position = 0;
const unsigned char *firstFourBytes;
```

Above you declared `firstFourBytes` as a *pointer*, you have **not** allocated a buffer which can hold 4 bytes, and `firstFourBytes` itself is uninitialised.

```
[stream getBytes:&firstFourBytes range:NSMakeRange(position , 4)];
```

`getBytes:range:` expects a pointer to a buffer into which it can copy the bytes. You pass `&firstFourBytes`, which is a pointer to the storage used for the variable `firstFourBytes`, so you are asking the bytes be copied not into a buffer pointed at by `firstFourBytes` but into `firstFourBytes` itself. Fortunately for you you only ask for 4 bytes and `sizeof(unsigned char *)` is 4 (32-bit software) or 8 (64-bit software) bytes, so the bytes fit...

```
uint32_t test = *(uint32_t*)firstFourBytes;
```

However you now take those four bytes, which is your big-endian 4 byte integer, and use them (and 4 extra garbage bytes if 64-bit) as a pointer into memory and try to read a four byte integer from this random location. It *may* work and return garbage, it may just crash.

```
position+=4;
```

**How To Do It**

You need:

1. A buffer of the right size.
2. For this buffer to be aligned correctly for the type of data you are reading, e.g. for 32-bit data your buffer should normally be on a four-byte boundary. (This is not an absolute requirement, off alignment stores & loads are supported on *some* platforms, but if so are usually much slower.)
3. To convert from big-endian to whatever your computer uses.

The easiest way to address (1) and (2) is to declare a variable of the required type - the compiler will handle the alignment and (Objective-)C allows you to take the address of any variable and use it as a byte buffer. So you start with:

```
UInt32 uint32bytes;
```

You can now read the required number of bytes directly into this variable by treating it as a byte buffer:

```
[stream getBytes:&uint32bytes
           range:NSMakeRange(position, sizeof(UInt32))
];
```

Note: You **must** check the supplied range is within `stream` before making this call as `getBytes:range:` will throw an exception if it isn't.

Now you have the 4 bytes in `uint32bytes` but they are in big-endian order and your platform might be little-endian (as the x86 is). To address that Apple provides the [Byte Order Utilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/index.html), a collection of functions to convert data of different sizes between endian formats. The function you are looking for is `CFSwapInt32BigToHost` which converts from big-endian to whatever your platform (host) uses - so on a big-endian platform it does nothing, on a little-endian platform it swaps the bytes. So you can now:

```
UInt32 result = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(uint32bytes);
```

and you have your result.

You can apply this template to other types, in your case `UInt16`, along with using the appropriate function from the Byte Order Utilities.

HTH